# Bucle de números random

Tags: java

quisiera saber como hacer un bucle de números random.
Tengo esta condición que entre un rango de hora me manda números aleatorios, respetando el rango de números a mostrar, ademas estoy diciendo que cada cierto tiempo me arroje un dato, en esta ocasión en de 6000 milisegundos. Esto lo estoy haciendo en javaNetbeans.

```
 if(hour>=0 && hour<=5){           
      maximo = 100;
      minimo = 60;
      Thread.sleep(60000); 
    }
```

Este es el ciclo for que estoy usando donde por ahora solo muestro 3 datos, pero yo quiero cambiar eso a que sea un bucle hasta que la hora cambie,y que no pare de arrojar numeros random.

```
  for(int i =0; i<3; i++){      
        int numero = (int) (Math.random() * maximo) + minimo;      
       return numero System.out.println(numero);                
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo cambiaría el if por un while, es lo que quieres, que no deje de mandar números hasta que la hora cambie

```
  int numero;
  maximo = 100;
  minimo = 60;
  while(hour>=0 && hour<=5){ //Comparamos hour recogido de algún método anterior a este bucle o inicializado
   numero = (int) (Math.random() * maximo) + minimo;      
   System.out.println(numero);           
   //Aquí método que actualice hour
   //Thread.sleep(6000); Tiempo parada bucle 
  }
```